# MongoDB - Embedding two collections into one

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have got 2 collections and I would like to re-design the database and put everything in one collection. 
Collection 1: **cars** and Collection 2: **reviews**. I wanna put all the data from reviews to cars collection. They have got matching **id_product**, So every car has **id_product** and every review has **id_product** as well.

Here's what I came up with :

```
var Acursor = db.getCollection('reviews').find({}, {_id:0});
              while (Acursor.hasNext()) {
              var nextDoc = Acursor.next();
              var textReview = nextDoc.reviewerID;
              var id_product = nextDoc.id_product;
              db.getCollection('cars').update({id_product:id_product},
              {$set: { textReview:textReview,}},
              {multi:true});
     };
```

I run the code without any errors and at first I thought that it worked, but the problem is that if there were 2 reviews for one car, only one review got transferred to the other collection. Any idea how to transfer all the reviews that are paired with the id_product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `{$set: { textReview:textReview}}`, Here you're updating a field every time, So if there are two reviews for a car, then the first one will be written to **textReview** field & when it's time for second review it will overwrite existing value.

Instead you can do `{$push: { textReview:textReview}}`, So for the first time it will create an array **textReview** & thereafter your query will append new elements to existing array.

**Ref :** [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html)

But if your MongoDB version is >=`4.2` then I would recommend to write an aggregation on **reviews** collection using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) to merge two collections & then use [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html) to write results to **cars** collection instead of read & write operation through code.